# How to freeze first column using Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using the following code to freeze the first column of my excel sheer generated using openpyxl. But this is not working and showing me an error.

```
dim_holder = DimensionHolder(worksheet=worksheet)
    for col in range(worksheet.min_column, worksheet.max_column + 1):
        dim_holder[get_column_letter(col)] = ColumnDimension(
            worksheet, min=col, max=col, width=20)

    # worksheet.column_dimensions.group(2, 10)
    dim_holder['A'] = ColumnDimension(
        worksheet, min=1, max=1, width=35)

    worksheet.column_dimensions = dim_holder
    worksheet.freeze_panes = 'A'
```

How can I freeze the entire first column, so that it will be sticky when I do horizontal scrolling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As not all code is present, but you have mentioned that you are using openpyxl, I am going to assume that. To freeze panes, you need to give the cell. That will freeze the panes above and to the left of the same. So, when you give `A`, it will not help, need to change it to `B1` instead. A simple example is given below.

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('YourFile.xlsx')
ws=wb['YourSheet']
c = ws['B1']  ## Freeze everything to left of B (that is A) and no columns to feeze
ws.freeze_panes = c
wb.save('YourFile.xlsx')
```